# How do I get and download my gcs.keyfile for Google Cloud Storage HMAC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, google-cloud-storage, rails-activestorage

So I am trying to upload my images to Google Cloud Storage. I have already set up the bucket and the rails project.

[Google Cloud Storage Bucket for Rails Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG6Rm.png)

I have been following this tutorial, I couldn't find anything recent, and it's **2 years old** https://medium.com/@iachieve80/rails-6-0-upload-images-using-active-storage-and-google-cloud-services-tutorial-538f818a6f30.

Up to this part of the tutorial [Download the JSON File step from the tutorial above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAVKo.png) is where I am stuck.

Because after that step you have to configure your `config/storage.yml` file and uncomment these lines:

```
# Remember not to checkin your GCS keyfile to a repository
# google:
#   service: GCS
#   project: your_project
#   credentials: <%= Rails.root.join("path/to/gcs.keyfile") %>
#   bucket: your_own_bucket-<%= Rails.env %>
```

If also look at the documentation for ActiveStorage https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#google-cloud-storage-service its a JSON file but I don't know how to arrange the necessary information like the access keys and whatnot.

I have the following gems installed `Gemfile`:

```
## Google-Cloud Storage - https://rubygems.org/gems/google-cloud-storage
gem 'google-cloud-storage', '~> 1.36', '>= 1.36.1'

## ActiveStorage - https://rubygems.org/gems/activestorage
gem 'activestorage', '~> 7.0', '>= 7.0.2.3'
```

If you need anymore information please let me and know and thanks in advance.

**PS: THIS IS MY FIRST EVER QUESTION. SO FORGIVE ME**

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this solution yet but according to [this answer](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31586#issuecomment-354363273) `credentials` can take the values themselves instead of a path to the json file. So the sensitive values could be stored in environment variables.

I will try it shortly and update.

======EDIT======

Tried and it works. Also turns out [the docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#google-cloud-storage-service) offer a few other methods too.